# Why does the result of image shape different in cv2 and scipy.misc

Tags: python, opencv, scipy, vision, imread

I use cv2 and scipy.misc to imread the same image, but the shape of the image different.

The one with scipy.misc turns out (1010,250).

[image: The one with scipy.misc turns out (1010,250)]

The one with cv2 turns out (1010,250,3).

[image: The one with cv2 turns out (1010,250,3)]

I wonder why the result different?

Comment: Is the input image grayscale? You're calling `cv2.imread` without specifying the second parameter, which means all images will be loaded as BGR (no matter how they're stored). Presumably the default behaviour of `scipy.misc.imread` is to read the file as is.

Comment: Code should be included as text and formatted as code by indenting with four spaces, or using the code format button in the WYSIWYG editor. Images of code are not searchable, or accessible.

Answer (score 0):

Presumably it is because `scipy.misc.imread` is returning an image with a single value per pixel (flattened to monochrome, or just RGB in a single value), whereas cv2 returns each RGB value in the final dimension.

Note also that docs show `scipy.misc.imread` as being deprecated: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.misc.imread.html#scipy.misc.imread

Probably best to avoid this anyway.